# Diferencia en Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy trabajando con el servicio Api rest en Codeigniter mi consulta es:

Tengo un json que me devuelve todos los alumnos del mini sistema1, en el mini sistema 2 tengo una tabla que se llama Asignar donde guardo el id del alumno y otros datos, mi problema está en realizar la consulta, que despues de guardar un alumno en asignar (`id_alumno`) me muestre los alumnos que no estén esa tabla
Este es el código que estuve utilizando :

```
  $datos=array_values(array_diff_key($jsonAlumno, $jsonAsignar));
```

esto solo me compara los `id(alumno)` con el `id(Asignar)` pero yo debo comparar `id(Alumno)` `id_alumno(Asignar)` con esto haría la diferencia y obtendría los que no están en la tabla Asignar pero no me está funcionando obviamente, y estoy re perdida.
Los datos estan asi

Tabla Alumno en el sistema1 que traigo con el json
Tabla Asignar en el sistema2 
 el resultado que deseo obtener son los alumnos que no estan en la tabla Asignar
    public function compara(){

```
  $id = $this->session->userdata('usuario_id'); 
  $usuario = $this->Model_Usuario->find($id);
  $escuela= $usuario->escuela_id;



$curl = new Curl();
$curl->get('http://localhost:8000/tesis/alumnorest/alumno?format=json'); 


        $jsonA = $curl->response;       
        $jsonAlumno=json_decode(json_encode($jsonA), true);   

        $jsonAsignar= $this->Model_Asignar->all();      
        $long = count($jsonAsignar);                 

        $datos=array_values(array_diff_key($jsonAlumno, $jsonAsignar));

        $jsonDatos=json_decode(json_encode($datos), true);   
        $longitud=count($datos);


        foreach ($jsonDatos as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['escuela_id']==$escuela){                                    

            $datos1[] = array('id' => $value['id'],
                              'persona_name' => $value['persona_name'],
                              'persona_dni' => $value['persona_dni'],
                              'persona_cuil' => $value['persona_cuil'],
                              'curso_name' => $value['curso_name'] );

                                    $resultado=json_encode($datos1); 

         }
        }
          echo ($resultado);  








  $this->load->helper('url');
```

}

Me podrían ayudar por favor que esto me tiene de cabeza y desde ya gracias.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow. En la pregunta, a pesar de las dos ediciones que hemos hecho tanto @AlfredoPaz  como yo, no termina de entenderse lo que hace el programa ni lo que quieres lograr. Quizá convendría que revises el planteamiento, siendo un poco más clara e incluso poniendo un ejemplo de cómo están los datos y otro de cómo quieres el resultado final. Puedes hacerlo [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/193777/edit). Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

en lugar de usar `array_diff_key` que verifica por el key del array deberias usar `array_udiff` que te da la posibilidad de verificar por cualquier valor del array de objetos.

```
// declaramos esta funcion
function comparar_id_alumnos($alumno, $asignar)
{
    // si retorna 0 es q existe, otro valor es q no existe
    return $alumno['id'] - $asignar['id_alumno'];
}

...

// esto deberia darte la diferencia
$ret = array_udiff($jsonAlumno, $jsonAsignar, 'comparar_id_alumnos');
var_dump($ret); // solo imprime el resultado
```

el `array_udiff` quitara del $jsonAlumno los elmentos que coincidan con los elementos de $jsonAsignar, verificando el id y el id_alumno respectivamente, y esta diferencia te la retornara en $ret.